# Custom Pod classes not accessible

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have created my first Cocoa Pod along with the Example (Demo) App that is created.

My pod is called "PineKit"

I am able to import PineKit but unable to access any of the classes in the Pod

```
import PineKit
// Does not show an error

let a = PineConfig.height
// Use of unresolved identifier PineConfig
```

Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: Have you checked that `PineConfig` is a public class?

Comment: Oh god! That was the issue! Can't believe I've been development for a month now not knowing that "public" needs to be mentioned in this case.